# Mail Conversion Utility of a non-mail database using remote server

Tags: lotus-domino

i want to replace design of a non-mail database on my server with a template located on a remote server, using Mail Conversion Utility.

I try something like:

load convert -n mydb.nsf * !!template.ntf

but i always obtain:

Mail Upgrade Failed: Unable to open design template file ......Unable to find path to server

Note that:

- remote server is reachable, if i do  (to open a database) and i specify both IP and ServerName (so, servers are cross-certified)
- if i do the same conversion operation using a server in my LAN, it works

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it works with a template located on another server. I will suggest that you replicate the template to your server and do the design replace as usual.

Comment: But in LAN it works! My goal is to centralize all templates on a remote server and upgrade every morning hundreds of customer installation using a program that does this type of command

Comment: So you can reference another server on your local network with the "load convert" command? Does your server have network access to the remote server (notice the "Unable to find path to server" error)?

Comment: Yes, in my local network i can. My server has access to remote server (if i do "Open server" from administrator using IP/server-name access is granted)

Comment: the problem was to create a server connection (in administrator) to the other server. Now the new problem is the cross certification between servers ("The Address Book does not contain a cross certificate capable of validating the public key"). I try but i can't resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're specifying an empty server name in the path to the template.  Have you tried putting the abbreviated name before the "!!"?

```
load convert -n mydb.nsf * removeServerName/OrgUnit/Org!!template.ntf
```

Comment: Just tried! It doesn't work...empty string was a typo mistake

Comment: I've posted an article on my blog, where i explain my solution: http://blog.redturtle.it/2013/04/12/how-to-automatically-refresh-your-database-in-silent-mode

Answer (score 0):

All of this is basic administration knowledge and has nothing to do with "coding". Nevertheless: If you run a command on a server, then this server executes the command. 
If you connect to a server using the admin- client, then YOU execute the command.

Therefor you need to enable your Server to:

a) Find the other server: You create a connection document from your server to the other server (of course network / firewalls have to configured)

b) Authenticate on the other server: To "prove" that your server really is who he pretends to be you need to exchange your servers' public key with the other domain. The process of doing so is called "cross certification" and instructions can be found in the Domino Administrator Help.

c) Be authorized by the other server: After proving the identity, your server has to be allowed to access the server and do what you want to do by putting in the right values in the security tab of the customers server

d) Be authorized to use the relevant databases on the other server (via ACL)

All of this needs to be checked in BOTH directions.